# Master/Details binding MVVM

Tags: mvvm, binding, uwp, master-detail

I have some problem with correct binding my folder with images to master details and other operation with them.
So, I have model of folder and image

```
public class AppFolder
{
    private long id;
    private List<AppImage> appImages;

    public AppFolder() { }

    public List<AppImage> AppImages { get => appImages; set => appImages = value; }
    public long Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
}

public class AppImage
{
    private int id;
    private string title;
    private ImageSource appImageURL;

    public AppImage() { }
    public AppImage(string title, ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        Title = title;
        AppImageURL = imageSource;
    }
    public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public string Title { get => title; set => title = value; }
    public ImageSource AppImageURL { get => appImageURL; set => appImageURL = value; }

}
```

And I bind List to Master/Details.

```
    public class UserPhotosViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService dataService;
    private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

    public UserPhotosViewModel(IDataService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService;
        this.navigationService = navigationService;

        Initialize();

    }

    private async Task Initialize()
    {         
        var item = new List<AppFolder>();
        try
        {
            item = await dataService.GetDataList();
            FolderList = item;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }      
    }

    private List<AppFolder> folderList;
    public List<AppFolder> FolderList
    {
        get { return folderList; }
        set
        {
            folderList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FolderList));

        }
    }
}
```

Example xaml file

```
    <controls:MasterDetailsView ItemsSource="{Binding FolderList}">
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>

            <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:AdaptiveGridView ItemsSource="{Binding AppImages}"
                                                OneRowModeEnabled="False"
                                                       ItemHeight="205"                                                      
                                                       DesiredWidth="205"     
                                                       SelectionMode="Multiple"     

                                                       Margin="0 6 0 0"    
                                               >
                        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <Grid Background="White" Margin="10">
                                    <Image                                                   
                                            Source="{Binding AppImageURL}"                 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"                  
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Stretch="Uniform"
                                            />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextTitle}"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

So, it's work correct and I saw my folders with images on page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlQxI.png)

Look nice and I think it all.
But when I want to add event and SelectedItem to AdaptiveGridView from MVVM model, I saw that it doesn't see them. Visual Studio show me that I could to write them in Model "AppFolder" but it's nonsens....

So, my question: How I can add event (binding command/method) to adaptive grid from UserPhotosViewModel?

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGX6V.png)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Could you post the "not working" code to help us understand?

Comment: Have you tried the [EventTriggerBehavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/EventTriggerBehavior) in UWP?

Comment: @MartinZikmund I try to add doubleTapped event and Selected Item for AdaptiveGridView for interaction with images. 1) User select N images and delete them (example) 2) User double click on image and program send folder with this image and other to page and binding them to FlipView (imitation full screen viewer) I add screen in post, when VS offers me method or property from Folder model

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT
Yes, I try to add, but that way also offers to write event and property in model.
I use this way for settings in navigation panel (parent control for master/details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2) User double click on image and program send folder with this image and other to page and binding them to FlipView (imitation full screen viewer)
>
> I try to add, but that way also offers to write event and property in model. I use this way for settings in navigation panel (parent control for master/details)

You just need to add command property in your `AppFolder` class like the following:

```cs
public class AppFolder:ViewModelBase
{
    private long id;
    private List<AppImage> appImages;

    public AppFolder() { }

    public List<AppImage> AppImages { get => appImages; set => appImages = value; }
    public long Id { get => id; set => id = value; }

    public RelayCommand<object> relayCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your `UserPhotosViewModel`, you could declare a method for initializing this command.

Since I do not know what the `dataService.GetDataList()` is. I just change this place in your code and make a simple code sample for you.

```cs
private void Initialize()
{
    var item = new List<AppFolder>();
    try
    {
        List<AppImage> ls = new List<AppImage>();
        ls.Add(new AppImage() { Id = 1, Title = "aaa", AppImageURL = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg")) });
        ls.Add(new AppImage() { Id = 2, Title = "bbb", AppImageURL = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/2.jpg")) });
        item.Add(new AppFolder() { Id = 1, AppImages = ls,relayCommand=new RelayCommand<object>(DoubleTapCommand) });
        FolderList = item;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private void DoubleTapCommand(object obj)
{
    //the obj will be an AppFolder object
}
```

```xml
<controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:AdaptiveGridView x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding AppImages}"
                                            OneRowModeEnabled="False"
                                                   ItemHeight="205"                                                      
                                                   DesiredWidth="205"     
                                                   SelectionMode="Multiple"     
                                                   Margin="0 6 0 0">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
                            <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding relayCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Interactions:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Grid Background="White" Margin="10">
                                <Image                                                   
                                        Source="{Binding AppImageURL}"                 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"                  
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Stretch="Uniform"
                                        />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextTitle}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
```

> 1) User select N images and delete them (example)

About this requirement, I suggested that you'd better add a button to bind command for deleting selected items.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was help for me!